# Understanding the Java Heap

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine with 2 drives: C:\ and G:\

On the G:\ drive (the larger one), I have installed a third party tool that we use to generate PDFs on the file. It has it's own server (Corda Server) that allocates it's heap size (which I pushed up to 1.5GB). The Corda server came with a JRE to be able to run on Windows.

Since they have no visual tools, I needed to install the JDK to get VisualVM (I looked to see the heap, but they all needed to have the JDK.

I installed the JDK 1.7 on C:\program files\java.  After running the VisualVM, I only see that the heap size is only going to 30mb.  Did I something wrong? Is it monitoring the JVM correctly?

Help in the comments would be great, and I can clarify anything if this is not clear.

Comment: It might be that the heap has been allocated 1.5GB but is only using 30mb and so that is what is shown?

Comment: yeah, the problem arises when i originally set the corda heap to 256m, it would crash on large pdfs, which i'm running now. But now i have it at 1.5gb it seems fine. I'm trying to monitor it.

Comment: thx, i was looking at the local machine in the visualvm, and not the corda one. I see it all correctly now. Thx a lot.